# How can I find an R dataset with Factors & NA's

Tags: r

I'm looking for a standard data set attached to an R package that I can use to test code.  I usually use `iris` or `mtcars` but they only have a single factor variable and no missing values.  Any suggestions for packages / data sets with multiple factor variables and NA's, or ways to search the included R datasets for specific criteria?

Comment: The web is full of opensource datasets that might be helpful for you. Also look at Kaggle datasets

Comment: You can see all datasets in your installed packages by calling `data()`. A brief inspection suggests that `forcats::gss_cat` might be useful?

Comment: It might be more straightforward to use a package like wakefield or fakeR to generate simulated data with your desired characteristics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a programatic way to search a package's datasets for your desired characteristics:

```
available_datasets <- data(package='datasets')[['results']][, 3];

meets_reqs <- function(datasets) {
    sapply(datasets, function(ds) {
        dat <- get(sub(" .*", "", ds))
        hasfactors <- "factor" %in% sapply(dat, class)
        nas <- anyNA(dat)
        hasfactors && nas
    })
}

res <- meets_reqs(available_datasets)

res[1:3]
# AirPassengers                BJsales BJsales.lead (BJsales) 
#         FALSE                  FALSE                  FALSE 

res[res]
# attenu
#   TRUE
```